# How to send files to coreos from windows workstation

Tags: docker, coreos

I have some nodejs projects and other files that I want to put on the coreos private server, what is the easiest method to take files from the workstation (windows) and put them into the coreos system?

Is there anything I could do other than making a docker container with ftp?

The goal is to be able to type with my favorite editor with my pc and then bring it to coreos server in order to build docker files from here.

What are the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you have got. If you can connect with `ssh`, then I'd recommend using `scp` with `tar`ed files - this is the most simple solution, as you should have everything you need. You could also create some cloud and sync both PCs.

But honestly - you're a developer - why don't just use `git` and private repository?

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in a vote for [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/). I have been using it in a similar situation, happily, for quite a while.

Otherwise, stick with `git`.